# How can I subtract two NSUInteger variables?

Tags: ios, objective-c, subtraction

Is there any way of subtract two or more NSUInteger values with Objective-C?

This is my code

```
__block NSUInteger *removedElementsCount = 0;
__block BOOL lastIsSuperElement = NO;
// Get the elements not collapsed
[_elements enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  __nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * __nonnull stop) {
    if (_isHidingSubElementsBlock(obj)){
        //_collapseSubCellsAtIndexPathBlock(idx+_elementsOffset);
        [elementToRemove addObject:(Task *)obj];
        lastIsSuperElement = YES;
        [indexPathToRemove addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(idx-removedElementsCount) inSection:0]];
        removedElementsCount = 0;
    } else if (lastIsSuperElement){
        removedElementsCount++;
        lastIsSuperElement = NO;
    }
}];
```

When I try to create a new NSIndexPath with idx-removedElementsCount, I get the following error:

```
HTReorderTableCells.m:231:75: Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') and 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned int *'))
```

I have looked for a solution but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Do you mean a minus b?

Comment: Yes, but with NSUInteger

Comment: Yep there is a way. What you have tried and failed? Please show some code.

Comment: You need use  `__block NSUInteger removedElementsCount = 0;` without `*`. Where did you get it?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I was mistaken, thanks for you view.

Comment: @Cy-4AH is right. Accepted answer'll lose precision in 64bit environment. See my solution it is compatible with 64-bit environment.

Comment: This was not important in my case, but both of you are right. I have changed my accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use NSInteger for your solution.

```
NSUInteger value1 = 5;
NSUInteger value2 = 3;
NSInteger subs = value1 - value2;
```

In your code fix the declaration of `removedElementsCount` (remove *)

Comment: Why is `subs` an `NSInteger` instead of `NSUInteger`? The solution is not to use `NSInteger`. The solution is to fix the declaration of `removedElementsCount`.

Comment: It is NSInteger because (value1 - value2) can be negative. In the question he says "How can I subtract two NSUInteger variables?" so this is the answer. Anyway, I edited my answer.

Answer (score -2):

`removedElementsCount` isn't an `NSUInteger`, it's an `NSUInteger*` (a pointer to an integer).

Try changing the expression to dereference the pointer before subtraction.

```
idx - (*removedElementsCount)
```

Comment: It will cause `BAD_ACCESS`. Because there is `NULL` in `removedElementsCount`.

Comment: No, the proper solution is to make `removedElementsCount` an `NSUInteger` instead of an `NSUInteger *`.